# IBM watson i'm calling from mobile first http adapter i'm getting "resource not found" what can I do?

Tags: mobilefirst-adapters, watson-conversation

{ "error": "Resource not found", "isSuccessful": true, "responseHeaders": { "Connection": "Keep-Alive", "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8", "Date": "Thu, 11 May 2017 12:44:01 GMT", "ETag": "W/\"1e-EQXgN3/vZJRmPkOk8Nrjcw\"", "Server": "-", "Set-Cookie": "Watson-DPAT=Tfc%2Ffb091lHBQYLUseav%2BE2EP1FZboc%2ByZgVt67SJubV9XQeXgEFrRp2%2BBMFcogYGk4J2JsmimlbJaimYDmdvhXHBnDxYD5xdPz7OXakKm%2FRUfArPhKaXXdFL6p0QHRWk47W0FDsFWrUiZXryGo6CkkvP4ObIecdxgQLdelxzYKD7xjKZXyR2sMOkdBE0xK7rZkbUYooc8ivKzuZjsNQNiBVaASj03w67PjK2bk0JunAr7qZ5tjeZbeJXXMoyIpiy1NwLk%2Fx8xOZcEwd2cZAzAPTyI7uBIJ4YL5nQSvNLW0upfg5xklVZTCqX%2BAckndKDCbOUn7eBtxtsma%2FFuJyUfiqQVFtHU%2FnClppncI9fNFp0VHcgV%2BaAu4oTmCUhqYlfDhiwwYUra9FHdZE%2BNFqUZGY9fb2LIeeA0tGUAbrGTZJpL1rmMQ9qWzyNaU6T2ODfAfBt%2BpaWqbi%2F9cHis%2Bz41PEeeSNcS2jRVgLjQVcPM%2FqvDd%2FWoJyFAufQz1Dcuu2IWHfmM83eRMEarQa0RyPVxS9XG2IepzfzaDX9xLtkULTAvKIj6qrZJNAnCAAeAiNHzDvRnRQbz4NpgUr4X3pTy9T3caFMY1%2FxBR3qc%2FcUxNsF3FZvw6Qmm27vJm6a%2B0Xk1Dk5VM13D%2FhwE6%2BThHewZJ2EUo1IYViu9gmUvh3%2BcBcVEPY2gJdzJMTsgjA3yoeTdSazhVcWWVrFzinGQ1mse2kQuE2la5RuVSHNv30i2krWRXHnVLK%2B5563dptTiot8rPAKrVdFAYFm1K7HrUQg4qa8bNARdHdjGngs2W82MiMB1iBlwlsCXRpq13TEWspY1uOG4bmbVhuSW%2FTU7fyqZyDpZVOW0w3lB%2Bzjd5RPgio9nNlv5Y8hoG7F5RjaoKPeplTY6xCZPY%3D; path=/conversation/api; secure; HttpOnly", "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000;", "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked", "Vary": "Accept-Encoding", "X-Backside-Transport": "FAIL FAIL", "X-Client-IP": "182.74.170.126", "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff", "X-DNS-Prefetch-Control": "off", "X-DP-Watson-Tran-ID": "gateway-dp01-724674816", "X-Download-Options": "noopen", "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN", "X-Global-Transaction-ID": "724674816", "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block" }, "responseTime": 1590, "statusCode": 404, "statusReason": "Not Found", "totalTime": 1865 }

Comment: You should provide a lot more information. Specifically about the version of MFP you are using ,what you have configured etc.

Answer (score 0):

"Set-Cookie": "Watson-DPAT... and "isSuccessful": true tells that your request has reached the destination in general.

But "statusCode": 404, "statusReason": "Not Found" , tells that the specific resource you have requested is wrong.

Verify if you missed something in the path. Specifically around "path=/conversation/api"

Comment: the path is correct verified in  watson conversation page.

Comment: What if you try it outside of MFP? Does a direct REST call work? If so, try that and see if the URL that works and what you have configured in adapter is different

Comment: Tried for web app it is working from mfp not working